# Laravel eloquent relationships : difference betwen auth()->user()->favorites()->get() and auth()->user()->favorites

Tags: laravel

User Model :

```
    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
    }
```

Controller :

```
 //return auth()->user()->favorites()->get();
 //return auth()->user()->favorites;
```

can someone explain the **difference** betwen the two codes ?
and when i should use each one?

Comment: both codes works , but i want to know the difference

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties

Comment: I think youre looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656165/laravel-difference-between-model-builder-and-collection#:~:text=Builder%20%3A%20This%20is%20a%20layer,basically%20an%20array%20on%20steroids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain it practically:

If the above query looks like this

```
// return auth()->user()->favorites()->where('active', true)->get();
// return auth()->user()->favorites->where('active', true);
```

then its SQL query be like this

```
// SQL of first query
select * from `favorites` where `favorites`.`user_id` = 1 and `favorites`.`user_id` is not null and `active` = 1

// SQL of second query    
select * from `favorites` where `favorites`.`user_id` = 1 and `favorites`.`user_id` is not null
```

**Did you see differences in two SQL?**

Now, Let me explain it in words:

If you add some condition after `favorites()` like above, it will fetch all filtered result from database. But if you add some condition after `favorites` it will filter the result which is already fetched from the database.

***Although, I'm not good at explanations, I hope you understand clearly between the two codes.***