# There Are Any Difference at Timing When Select Data By ORM Laravel 6 Using This Two Ways?

Tags: laravel, orm, model

$user->follows

or That

$user->follows()

[Timeline Method That Return Data To View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j350v.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is `$user->follows` call an object from data and `$user->follows()` call a model method.

Comment: If I Have Many Users , That Make Any Difference  At Timing ?

Comment: @AHMEDKAMAL, Both are different things. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73610259/14151733